# Discord.py Issue with add_roles

Tags: python, discord.py

```
@client.command()
async def vmute(ctx, user, time, * reason) :
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="VcMuted" )
    await user.add_roles(role)
    print(user, role, time)
```

I have literally no idea what I am doing wrong. With `user` I end up with:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'add_roles'
```

with client (aka bot) I end up with:

```
AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'add_roles'
```

I have been searching like 10 stack pages, the API page, and googled for 1h. I have no Idea what I am missing here. If someone could tell me what the operator for removing roles is i'd appreciate it. that's kind of my one command and I am a newbie with python. Its just this little thing that i cant get to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`user` parameter is returning a string, specify a type using `type hints` like so `user: discord.Member`.

```
@client.command()
async def vmute(ctx, user: discord.Member, time, *reason):
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="VcMuted")
    await user.add_roles(role)
    print(user, role, time)
```

Comment: I love you ty soooo much. It works now... I shot myself 200 times. My whole thingy works

Comment: did I got the rest figured now. letse gooo